# Phone field matching rule does not work

Tags: duplicate-management

I'm trying to de-duplicate and prevent duplicate leads in SFDC based on Phone numbers. 
I created a matching rule for Phone field with "exact" match.

However, I found that it's allowing duplicate records with phone numbers which are just formatted differently:

1) (206) 251-7000

2) 2062517000

Why is that so? I though field of type "Phone" will automatically format any 10 digit number to (xxx) xxx-xxxx given the locale is set to English (USA)

Answer (score 3):

The UI automatically performs formatting, but the database does not. You may want to consider using the Fuzzy Match option, which will match the same numbers but differ in punctuation. If you still want to use an Exact Match, you'll want to set up a trigger, Process Builder, or Workflow Rule to format the field such that it matches the expected format.

Comment: No I do not see UI performing any formatting. I prepared a report and it showed 2 absolute duplicate record showing same phone numbers in above 2 formats. I had inserted the records from Excel which had the 2 rows in different formats for phone numbers and hence SFDC reflected the same as in Excel. But I thought phone field in Leads object in SFDC should be taking care of this automatically. How do I solve this?

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT If you use the Import Wizard, Excel, Data Loader, etc, you don't get any automatic formatting of phone numbers. This is done by the UI, not by the platform directly. Again, you need to either use Fuzzy Matching, or you need to create a customization that handles the punctuation for you.